# SQL - Get 10 records, ordered by a column, with some columns being unique

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a table with a column for timestamps, I want to get the 10 most recent records with particular columns being unique.

How can this be done?

## Example:

**Data:**

```
purchases
-----------------------------------------------------------------
timestamp   first_name    last_name   customer_id  product_name  purchase_amount
```

How can I get the 5 most recent customers who made a purchase, and the `product_name` and `purchase_amount`?

**Result:**

```
James, Jackson, 1234, 'foo', 432.123
Tim, McTimothy, 321, 'bar', 5124.11
Bob, Bobbertson, 55, 'foo', 432.123
Claire, Rando, 191, 'tv', 700.00
Jimbo, Manman, 631, 'ps4', 450.00
```

## What I've tried:

This query fails since it would require an aggregation on `product_name` and `purchase_amount`, but we don't want an aggregation, just the latest value.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, customer_id, product_id
FROM purchases
GROUP BY first_name, last_name, customer_id
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This would be easier in a modern db that supports a lateral join/apply. Just put your LIMIT 5 in a query on the purchases table, group by customer_id and order by max timestamp to get the customers you need, and then use that alongside an apply/lateral join to get each customer's most recent purchase. Sadly, MySql has slipped out of the "modern db" category: no apply/lateral join, no windowing functions, no CTEs (unless you're lucky enough to be running the 8.01 service release), no full join... I could go on, and _all_ of these are available in Oracle, Sql Server, and Postgresql.

Comment: @Don P - is it possible to add one auto increment primary key column to this table?

Comment: @FathahRehmanP unfortunately no, there is no primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM 
(  
    SELECT customer_id, MAX(timestamp) last_purchase_time
    FROM purchases
    GROUP BY customer_id
    ORDER BY MAX(timestamp) DESC
    LIMIT 5
) lp
INNER JOIN purchases p ON p.customer_id = lp.customer_id and p.timestamp = lp.last_purchase_time
```

The nested query gets the last purchase time for each customer, and further limits the nested result set to the 5 most recent customers. We then connect this back to the purchases table so we can see the full purchase data for the last purchase by each of those customers. This does make the assumption that a customer could not have two purchases at the exact same instance, but that's probably safe.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a `rank` column that would act as an `id`, something like this:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, customer_id, product_name
FROM
 (SELECT   first_name, last_name, customer_id, product_name, @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank
  FROM     purchases p1, (SELECT @rank := 0) r
  ORDER BY timestamp DESC) p2
GROUP BY first_name, last_name, customer_id
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm assuming customer_id is unique. so we only need to use customer_id in 
group clause

```
   select  * from  purchases p2 where 
       concat(UNIX_TIMESTAMP((p2.timestamp)),'_',p2.customer_id)  
         in ( 
                  select concat(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(max(p.timestamp)),'_',p.customer_id)
                  from purchases p group by p.customer_id order by p.timestamp desc
            ) limit 10
```